# How to use ToList on Collection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) indicates the the class `Collection<T>` has a method `ToList()` in the Extension section.

How I can use this method?

Comment: Extension method: add `using System.Linq`

Comment: `ToList()` is a Linq extension method, add a `using System.Linq` to be able to use it.

Comment: Others have indicated how to bring the ToList extension method into scope, but the bigger question is WHY do you want to cast the collection to a List<T>. Collection<T> implements IList<T>. Perhaps it would be better to just work with the IList<T> instead of adding to the memory overhead of copying the object pointers into a second List.

Answer (score 6):

This documentation is a bit misleading.  The type `Collection<T>` doesn't have this method directly.  Intstead it's defined as an extension method on `System.Linq.Enumerable`.  Adding the `using` directive for `System.Linq` should fix the problem

```
using System.Linq; 

...

Collection<T> col = ...;
List<T> list = col.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a reference to `System.Core.dll`, and add, at the top of your C# file, `using System.Linq;`

You can see this in the [documentation for ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
Namespace:  System.Linq
Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)
```

Also, since the declaration is an extension method (`this IEnumerable<TSource> source`), you'll have to using the using statement to refer to it, as it's defined on a different type (`Enumerable`).

Answer (score 0):

you call `ToList()` on an instance of it.

```
myCollection.ToList()
```

The extension method available on all types that implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

This requires `using System.Linq` in your cs file, and a reference to `System.Core` both of which are added by default in current versions of VS when targeting .net 3.5 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your file.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ToList` method is an extension method defined in the `System.Linq` namespace, so to use the method you must include a using statement to `System.Linq`. Once you do that, it's as simple as `yourCollection.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

ToList() is an extension method.  Do you have the correct namespace (System.Linq) imported and referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a commandline project will not have a reference to System.Data.Linq in it, so even if you add a using statement, you won't get intellisense or proper compiling on the project. I.e. When you do like

```
Datacontext dc = new DataContext();
dc.Tablename.W
```

and when you start typing W you expect to see "where" but you don't. Adding a reference to the project fixes this.

Open "References" folder in your project. Look for a reference to System.Data.Linq. If it's not there, right click on the References folder, and select "Add Reference..." then click the .NET tab and look for System.Data.Linq, select it and hit OK. Everything should now work.

I use Where as an example, because that's where I always discover it, but the ToList() etc is the same.